# How Catch Angular JS ng-click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
<button ng-click="btn_save">Save</button>
<button ng-click="btn_update">update</button>
```

I want  to cach and display **alert** for **ng-click event** of **btn-save** only **anjular js**.give me some best practice for done this job.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add an app and a controller where you will implement your logic.

The aplication logic goes in the controllers. Aviod putting it in the templates.

Example:

**template**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <button ng-click="btn_save()">Save</button>
 <button ng-click="btn_update()">update</button>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.btn_save = function(){
        alert("Button save clicked!")
    }
}
```

Is here, in the controller where you will implement the btn_save logic. In this case, the function throw an alert dialog when user clicks on button.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xeq23e19/

Hope that helps.